# How to retrieve the value in a Dictionary based on key in VBA

Tags: vba, dictionary

I have a dictionary as such:

```
Set Desk = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For Index = 1 To NoOfDesks
   Desk.Add Cells(15 + Index, 4).Value, Index
Next
```

I am interested in getting the value based on the index. I tried doing this:

```
MsgBox Desk.Items()(1)
```

But I am not able to get the Value. It is returning a integer. It should be a string. Need some guidance on this.

Comment: Have a read on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4(v=vs.84).aspx (Dictionary Object)

Comment: Dictionary? Then you must read this : [Dictionary VBA](http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Dictionary_en.html). If you still have questions (which I doubt after reading this), then post your code. Above question is already answered in the link posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting exactly what you asked for: when you added the items, you specified `Cells(15 + Index, 4)` for a *Key*, and `Index` for an *Item*. `Index` being an `Integer`, you're getting an `Integer`.

If possible, add a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` instead of late-binding with `CreateObject`: you'll get IntelliSense, which makes it much easier to work with an unfamiliar API:

[image: Add(Key,Item) tooltip]

Your code would look like this:

```
Set Desk = New Dictionary
For Index = 1 To NoOfDesks
   Desk.Add Index, Cells(15 + Index, 4).Value
Next
```

One thing to note, is that dictionary keys must be unique - you're [un]lucky to not have duplicates in column 4, otherwise it would be quite apparent that you have inverted the dictionary's key and value.

Comment: I agree to this one. I always use *Early Bind* during development. Then revert to late binding if only necessary after the code is tried and tested +1.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim Desk As Object, NoOfDesks&, Index&, Key As Variant
    Set Desk = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    NoOfDesks = 100

    For Index = 1 To NoOfDesks
       Desk.Add Cells(15 + Index, 4).Value, Index
    Next
    For Each Key In Desk
        Debug.Print Key, Desk(Key)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This will blow up if `Cells(15 + Index, 4)` has any duplicate values. OP wants the **values**, not the keys.

Comment: @retailcoder I know that if values will be not uniq then error will apear, but question was how to retrieve the value based on a key. So I suppose that my example will show it, how values and key can be retrieved. Thks for downvote

Comment: I downvoted because this answer addresses the symptom, not the cause; that makes it misleading and leaves OP with code that only *seems* to work as intended. I will happily revert my vote if it is edited to better explain the implications. Cheers!